# Accessing camera in Wp7, with zoom

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, camera, windows-phone-7.1

I'm creating an application for WP7 where the background of it (a grid) receives the image from the camera. Here is how it works:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="video" />
        </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera m_camera;

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();

Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        m_camera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera();
        video.SetSource(m_camera);
    };
}
```

My question: Is there a way to access the zoom options of the camera with this? Or can I define the source as the camera totally zoomed in or out?

Comment: @abhinav That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You can manipulate a higher resolution image to fill the background with only the part that you'd like to zoom in on. See resolution example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202951%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)